# Multidomain authorization and SSO via keycloak with kerberos

Tags: ldap, keycloak, single-sign-on, kerberos

How to configure keycloak if there are the same user logins in different LDAP servers with Kerberos integration?
We configured user federation: selected ldap provider, configured parameters, set the value of `Username LDAP attribute` with `sAMAccountName`, configured Kerberos integration. We got users with short logins (`sAMAccountNames`). If we connect to another LDAP server that has the same short logins, we get “user exists” error.

We can solve the import problem if we use `userPrincipalName` attribute in LDAP settings, but in this case end-to-end authorization with kerberos does not work correctly: users enter their `sAMAccountNames`, keycloak can’t match them with `userPrincipalNames` and send users to login window.
How can we solve the problem?
It is not allowed to change LDAP server settings.